# Microsoft Graph and access without a user

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to upload and download files in my sharepoint online using a background task (daemon) that runs frequently in my ASP.NET Core app.  Because it's a background task, no user identity is used.  Instead, I tried to follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service), getting an access token using the `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` scope, as well as having my enterprise app on azure having particular permissions already granted by the admin.  [image: admin consent]

I'm able to get an access token using my app's client id and secret.  However when I try to request the drives on a particular site on sharepoint, it just stalls, hinting me that it can't reach the path.  I can reach this same path totally fine when I use my user credentials instead.

I think I may be missing a step or some azure administration-related task.  Below is the code snippet that shows I can get the access token, but stalls when getting the drives.

```
var client = new ConfidentialClientApplication(id, uri, cred, null, new SessionTokenCache());
var authResult = await client.AcquireTokenForClientAsync(new[] {"https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"});
var token = authResult.AccessToken;  // get token successfully
var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async request => {request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token)}));
// stalls below
var drives = await graphServiceClient.Sites[<sharepoint_host>].SiteWithPath(<known_path>).Drives.Request().GetAsync();
```

Using Microsoft Graph SDK within an ASP.NET Core 2 app.

Edit:  Below is an updated screenshot showing application permissions added and consented:
[image: updated screenshot]

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: I added a new screenshot showing application permissions, but still have issues.  Error message is: Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your image you have granted delegated permissions to the app. You need to grant application permissions. Delegated permissions only apply when acting on behalf of a user.

Comment: Although the above is correct that I needed to grant app permissions, this still did not work for me for some reason.  I'm looking at the decoded token I get and it does not contain any roles in it.  Not sure what to do here.

Comment: Okay, did you require the permissions and then press the Grant permissions button?

Comment: Yes, then it opens up a browser trying to load my localhost application but I get the error:  An error was encountered while handling the remote login. ---> System.Exception: Correlation failed.

Comment: I mean the Grant permissions / Grant admin consent button in the Azure portal.

Comment: Yes, there is a button and when clicking it, it opens a browser window directed to my localhost (which throws the error).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192278/discussion-between-los-morales-and-juunas).

Comment: @juunas Hello i am facing the same problem, can u suggest proper answer.